# Is there a way to pre-arrange the desktop icons of the guest user?

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce

I'm currently in the process of customizing kiosk systems and need to pre-arrange the desktop icons for the guest user in xubuntu.

Is there a way to do this?

I source the home dir of a static user and tried to pre-arrange there but the changes don't affect the guest user.

Comment: Is [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/103089/308164) of any help? If not, the solution is in [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession#Special_purpose_user). Basically, create a user account, with the preferences you want, and then link them to the guest account.

Comment: I'm already doing the user creation an linking to the guest account. But the icon arrangement doesn't get transfered to the guest account. The guest account basically generates its own placement.